# Open new ConEmu tab with the same working directory

Tags: windows, macros, conemu

I have a ConEmu macro for `Ctrl+T` which runs `Task("Powershell")`. My Powershell task just runs powershell with the argument `\dir %userprofile%`.

The Macro tab in "About ConEmu" says that the `Task` command can take a second argument for the directory:

`Task("Name"[,"Dir"])`
`- start task with specified name`

I'd like to make my macro open a new tab with the same working directory as the tab I'm looking at when I hit Ctrl+T. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

When you "CD" in powershell, it does not actually change current process directory (`SetCurrentDirectory` is not called). You may check this with ProcessExplorer for example.

So, you may run from your active powershell prompt

```
PowerShell -new_console
```

or do that with [GuiMacro](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/GuiMacro). Using GuiMacro you can set any desired hotkey for that action.

```
Print("\ePowerShell -new_console\n")
```

In theory, you may create new tab without using active powershell prompt, there is another [macro](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Whats_New#Build_130702), but you need to force your PowerShell to call `SetCurrentDirectory` explicitly. For example, you may override your `prompt` function in powershell profile.